# Validating user in put in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation

I have 4 `textboxes` in VB.NET and I have to validate user input in them. According to the data entered into the textboxes I have to display one of the following messages:

> Score 1 is blank
>
> Score 1 is not numeric
>
> Score 1 is not in the range: 0-10
>
> Score 1 is valid

I have to repeat this for `Score2`, `Score3`, and `Score4`.

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim vintScore As Integer = 1

    Private Sub btn_Clear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Clear.Click
        Call Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_DefaultValues_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_DefaultValues.Click
        Call DefaultValues()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_Validate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Validate.Click
        Call ValidateData(txt_score1.Text)
        Call ValidateData(txt_score2.Text)
        Call ValidateData(txt_score3.Text)
        Call ValidateData(txt_score4.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Clear()
        txt_score1.Text = ""
        txt_score2.Text = ""
        txt_score3.Text = ""
        txt_score4.Text = ""
        txt_category.Text = ""
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = "All Data Cleared!"
    End Sub

    Private Sub DefaultValues()
        Call Clear()
        txt_score1.Text = "4"
        txt_score2.Text = "1"
        txt_score3.Text = "2"
        txt_score4.Text = "4"
        txt_category.Text = "A"
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "TextBox values set to default values"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ValidateData(ByVal vScore As String)
        If (vScore = "") Then
            lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is blank"
        ElseIf Not (IsNumeric(vScore)) Then
            lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is not numeric"
        ElseIf (vScore < 0 And vScore > 10) Then
            lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is not in range: 0-10"
        Else
            lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is Valid"

        End If
        vintScore = vintScore + 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I am currently getting as output is:

> Score 4 is valid
>
> Score 8 is valid
>
> Score 12 is not numeric
>
> and so on...

Whereas what I am after is this:

> Score 1 is valid
>
> Score 2 is not numeric
>
> Score 3 is not in range: 0-10
>
> Score 4 is valid

like this...

Comment: What is the actual problem? That the score number is not correct? Is the validation result correct? You should not store `vintScore` in a class variable. Instead, pass the score number as a parameter to the `ValidateData` method. Furthermore, I would advice, to pass a `StringBuilder` to the method. `ValidateData` would append it's messages to the `StringBuilder` and the button's event handler would assign the `StringBuilder's` content to the label. So you have a clear separation of concerns.

Comment: The problem is that the lbl_StatusContent.Text is overlapping each previous result. I want all them in next line. Like this:

Score 1 is valid
Score 2 is valid
Score 3 is valid

Answer (score 0):

Pass the numbers as parameters:

```
Private Sub ValidateData(ByVal vScore As String, ByVal vintScore as String)
    If (vScore = "") Then
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is blank"
    ElseIf Not (IsNumeric(vScore)) Then
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is not numeric"
    ElseIf (vScore < 0 And vScore > 10) Then
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is not in range: 0-10"
    Else
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is Valid"
    End If
End Sub
```

Callers:

```
Private Sub btn_Validate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Validate.Click
    Call ValidateData(txt_score1.Text, "1")
    Call ValidateData(txt_score2.Text, "2")
    Call ValidateData(txt_score3.Text, "3")
    Call ValidateData(txt_score4.Text, "4")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comment, use a `StringBuilder`:

```
Private Sub btn_Validate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Validate.Click
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Call ValidateData(txt_score1.Text, 1, sb)
    Call ValidateData(txt_score2.Text, 2, sb)
    Call ValidateData(txt_score3.Text, 3, sb)
    Call ValidateData(txt_score4.Text, 4, sb)
    lbl_StatusContent.Text = sb.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateData(ByVal vScore As String, ByVal vintScore As Integer, sb As StringBuilder)
    If vScore = "" Then
        sb.AppendLine("Score " & vintScore & " is blank")
    ElseIf Not (IsNumeric(vScore)) Then
        sb.AppendLine("Score " & vintScore & " is not numeric")
    '...
End Sub
```